# Enabling Docker Remote API on Ubuntu 14.04 with daemon startup

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-api

I´m struggeling with the activation of Remote API for docker.

Already tried to set configuration by the following command:

DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"

in following files:

```
/etc/default/docker
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/docker.conf
```

Then restarted daemon by pkill and started again by docker daemon & but still not working for me. What did I miss?

```
root@ubuntu:~# docker info
 Containers: 7
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 6
 Images: 24
 Server Version: 1.11.2
 Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 139
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
 Kernel Version: 4.2.0-36-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 7.78 GiB
 Name: ubuntu
enter code here
```

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 editing the file `/etc/default/docker` was enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `docker daemon &` by hand ignores all configuration files. Those files are referenced when you start Docker with the OS upstart commands, or an `/etc/init.d/docker start`. To bind to the port when starting by hand, you'd need to pass the argument there: `docker daemon -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375`. Note that this allows anyone with access to the local network full root access on your machine.

Comment: Nice, well to know. `/etc/init.d/docker start` starts with a process nr as output but still message _cannot connect to docker daemon_. Same message for `service docker (re)start`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the docker daemon config and having to restart it, you can use Sherpa to open up a path to the remote API via remote-proxy. Something like:

```
docker run -d \
--name sherpa \
-e CONFIG='[
    { 
        "Path" : "/",
        "Access": "allow",
        "Addresses": ["10.0.0.0/8"]
    }
]' \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
-p 4550:4550 \
djenriquez/sherpa --allow
```

would give you access on port 4550 and only accepts requests from source clients in the 10.0.0.0/8 space. You can customize all kinds of ACLs for the remote API also. You can run a `docker run` script on start up, if this is easier.

Checkout the introductory post here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/easily-enable-docker-remote-api-sherpa-dj-enriquez or directly to the repo here: https://hub.docker.com/r/djenriquez/sherpa/

Answer (score 1):

1. update /lib/systemd/system/docker.service

- `sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/docker.service`
  in [Service] section, change the value of ExecStart to be:
- `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`
  and save the file

2. restart docker service:

- `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
- `sudo systemctl restart docker`

3. verify
   run one of the following commands:

- `ps aux | grep dockerd`  
  The expected result will look like below:
  `root       4522  0.0  2.0 417112 81476 ?        Ssl  20:36   0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`
- `curl 127.0.0.1:2375/info`
  The expected result will be a long json string
- `netstat -nlp`
  The following will be shown:
  `tcp6       0      0 :::2375                 :::*                    LISTEN      -`
- `sudo docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 ps`
  The running containers will be shown

Above works for Ubuntu 14.04